# Do String.Encoding.utf16 and String.Encoding. utf16BigEndian mean the same thing i.e UTF16BigEndian?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, foundation

I have bytes for a string encoded with utf16 big endian. These bytes are read by me from a file shared with me by my colleague who confirms that string is utf16 bigendian.

For demo purpose I read the file to interpret the string. The code is as below:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: ViewController.self)
guard let url = bundle.url(forResource: "TestBingEndian", withExtension: "txt") else { return }
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        print(data)

let bigEndianString = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf16BigEndian)
print("bigEndianString: \(bigEndianString!)")

let littleEndian = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf16LittleEndian)
print("littleEndian: \(littleEndian!)")

let endiannessNotSpecifiedString = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf16)
print("endiannessNotSpecifiedString: \(endiannessNotSpecifiedString!)")
```

The output for the `bigEndianString` is what was expected.

The output for `littleEndian` was not useful as it was garbage for my case.

The output for `endiannessNotSpecifiedString` was also as expected and matched with the `bigEndianString`.

So my question is, are .utf16 and .utf16BigEndian the same thing?

PS: My machine is little endian. I thought .utf16 should be what my machines endianness is. But it turns out to be bigendian as per my tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***So my question is, are .utf16 and .utf16BigEndian the same thing?***

No. The right UTF-16 needs to contain BOM at the top of the file.

```
let str = "Hello, World!"

let dataUTF16 = str.data(using: .utf16)!
print(dataUTF16 as NSData)

let dataUTF16BE = str.data(using: .utf16BigEndian)!
print(dataUTF16BE as NSData)

let dataUTF16LE = str.data(using: .utf16LittleEndian)!
print(dataUTF16LE as NSData)
```

Output:

```
<fffe4800 65006c00 6c006f00 2c002000 57006f00 72006c00 64002100>
<00480065 006c006c 006f002c 00200057 006f0072 006c0064 0021>
<48006500 6c006c00 6f002c00 20005700 6f007200 6c006400 2100>
```

0xff, 0xfe represents the BOM in little endian. In big endian, it will be 0xfe, 0xff.

With `.utf16` you can read the right UTF-16 data (I mean having the right BOM), even in a endian mismatching platform.

Put `print(data as NSData)` and check the first two bytes of your `data`. I guess it contains 0xfe, 0xff (BOM in big endian.)

---

Seems my guess was wrong, and `.utf16` in Apple's Foundation prefers Big Endian than the platform's native endian, when BOM is not found. (<s>Maybe there's some historical reason, as Apple used to use Big Endian platforms, 68k or Power-PC.</s>As with Martin R's comment, it is defined in The Unicode Standard. Seems I need to refresh my knowledge.)

But you should better specify `.utf16BigEndian` when you know your data does not contain BOM and in Big Endian, `.utf16` for data containing the right BOM.

```
let str = "Hello, World!"

let dataUTF16 = str.data(using: .utf16)!
print(dataUTF16 as NSData)

let strUTF16asUTF16 = String(data: dataUTF16, encoding: .utf16)
debugPrint(strUTF16asUTF16) //->Optional("Hello, World!")
let strUTF16asUTF16BE = String(data: dataUTF16, encoding: .utf16BigEndian)
debugPrint(strUTF16asUTF16BE) //->Optional("䠀攀氀氀漀Ⰰ 圀漀爀氀搀℀")
let strUTF16asUTF16LE = String(data: dataUTF16, encoding: .utf16LittleEndian)
debugPrint(strUTF16asUTF16LE) //->Optional("Hello, World!")
```

When almost all the characters are made of ASCII characters, some sort of predicting the endianness would work, but when most of them are made of non-ASCII characters, such predictions may be wrong.This applies if you are predicting the endianness.

But in general you should be using the unicode standard which states that if there is No BOM to be found, you should treat the bytes as big endian.

Comment: You generated the bytes from the string programmatically. I did print my bytes as NSData as you said and 0xfe, 0xff are missing. BOM is not present in the bytes that I read from the file. So how is the endianness decided in this case?

Comment: My out is: <00480061 00720065 00730068 00200050 00690073 0065>

Clearly BOM is missing here.

Comment: @RohanBhale, thanks for clarifying, my guess was wrong, but I can show you some example that `.utf16` and `utf16BigEndian` works differently.

Comment: You are right. I did some additional reading here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark.

Comment: If there is no BOM, it is possible to guess whether the text is UTF-16 and its byte order by searching for ASCII characters (i.e. a 0 byte adjacent to a byte in the 0x20-0x7E range, also 0x0A and 0x0D for CR and LF). A large number (i.e. far higher than random chance) in the same order is a very good indication of UTF-16 and whether the 0 is in the even or odd bytes indicates the byte order. However, this can result in both false positives and false negatives.

In all there is a chance that .utf16 might fail in some cases. They predict it using patterns and predictions can fail.

Comment: Thanks for detailed comment. In fact, I did not know Apple's `.utf16` used Big Endian as default (not guessing endianness, not using platform endian). Seems you know very well now, which encoding you should use for your data.

Comment: Apparently [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring) still applies to Swift strings: *“When creating an NSString object from a UTF-16-encoded string (or a byte stream interpreted as UTF-16), **if the byte order is not otherwise specified, NSString assumes that the UTF-16 characters are big-endian,** unless there is a BOM (byte-order mark), in which case the BOM dictates the byte order.”*

Comment: @MartinR Interesting, so Apple does not predict(wiki suggests there should be prediction in such a case). It assumes it to be big endian.

Comment: @RohanBhale: That Wiki article also cites from the Unicode standard: *“The UTF-16 encoding scheme may or may not begin with a BOM. However, when there is no BOM, and in the absence of a higher-level protocol, the byte order of the UTF-16 encoding scheme is big-endian.”*

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. That also clarifies my underlying doubt, why are there no applications failing, due to this. So there is a clear standard to assume BigEndian in case the BOM is missing.